# Does heat make a difference on how minerals are attracted in an electromagnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, elements

In electric hot water tanks why do calcium quickly form on the heating elements? Is this magnetism sped up by heat?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of calcium salts dissolved in the 'hard' water. When the water is heated the solubility (the mass per litre that can be dissolved) decreases and the calcium salt precipitates (becomes solid) on the nearest surface, which may be the heating element. - This effect is not related to electromagnetism, though at some point a company claimed to be able to reduce the problems with hard water with a very strong magnet...